# Annotate non-model attribute in Django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model `Event` which has a `ManyToManyField` named users. I want to get all the events with an extra attribute which denotes whether a specific user belongs to this event or not.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

# Expected code format
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
events = // Event query
print events[0].your_event // It should be True if above user is part of this event else False
```

Here is the code which I tried

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, BooleanField
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
Event.objects.annotate(your_event=Case(when(users=user, then=True), default=False, output_field=BooleanField()))
```

**Problem with above code**: If an `Event` object has multiple users (let 4) then it is returning 4 objects which has `your_event` as `False` in three objects and `True` in one object. But I want only object for each 
event.

I believe a better solution can exist for this purpose.

Comment: Well I'm already surprised this works. I would expect that this would simply construct for every `Event` a number of copies (the number of users attached to it), and for every user, it would then denote whether it is *that* specific user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You are right, it is returning multiple copies of the same Event, how can I overcome it?